# Find trigonometric identities from an expression

Tags: integration, trigonometry, fourier-analysis

I was wondering how come these two lines are equal to each other.

$$\frac2\pi\left[
\frac{\sin[\pi(1+2n)x]}{1+2n}+
\frac{\sin[\pi(1-2n)x]}{1-2n}\right]^{1/2}_0 \tag1$$
$$\frac{2\cos\pi n}{\pi}\left(\frac1{1+2n}+\frac1{1-2n}\right)=\frac4\pi\frac{(-1)^n}{1-4n^2} \tag2$$

When I calculated $(1)$ I got:
$$2\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\pi (1+2n)} +\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\pi (1-2n)}\right) \tag3$$

Where does the $\cos\pi n$ come from? I guess it has something to do with trigonometric identities, but I really can't see it.

Comment: $\cos \pi n=(-1)^n$…

Comment: aint sin(pi/2 + pi*n) = sin(pi/2 - pi* n) = (-1)^n+1? (-1)^n+1?

Comment: @insipidintegrator i do get that. but i dont understand how the cos came from in the first place... i tried doing it my way on the buttom because i thought  $$sin(pi/2 + pi*n) = sin(pi/2 - pi *n) = (-1)^n+1?$$

Comment: How do you get $\sin(\pi/2-\pi n)=(-1)^{n+1}$? It’s $(-1)^n$. Check with a few values n=0,1,2,3,….  Also, use “\” before pi to type $\pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that
$$\sin (\tfrac12 \pi(1+2n))=\sin (\tfrac12 \pi(1+2n))=(-1)^n$$
Then
$$\frac2\pi\left[ \frac{\sin[\pi(1+2n)x]}{1+2n}+
\frac{\sin[\pi(1-2n)x]}{1-2n}\right]^{1/2}_0$$

$$=\frac2\pi\left( \frac{  \sin[\tfrac12\pi(1+2n)]}{1+2n}+
\frac{ \sin[\tfrac12\pi(1-2n)]}{1-2n}\right)$$

$$=\frac {(-1)^n2}\pi\left( \frac{ 1}{1+2n}+\frac{1}{1-2n}\right)$$
$$=\frac {(-1)^n2}\pi\left( \frac{ 2}{1-4n^2}\right)$$
$$=\frac4\pi\frac{(-1)^n}{1-4n^2} \tag2$$